# Connect ADF to Oracle DB hosted on Azure linux VM without SHIR

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, virtual-machine

I am trying to connect to oracle datasource from ADF using linked services which resides on an AZURE VM with private IP address
and the configuration of the VM is not windows it is LINUX and this is the reason I am not able to setup SHIR in the VM to connect to my ADF.

Is there any other way to connect to the oracle database which resides on the LINUX AZURE VM?

Please provide your suggestions.

when I tried to connect to AZURE VM oracle data source I am getting error [08001] [microsoft ODBC oracle wire protocol driver] Connection refused verify host name and port number.

Comment: Can you set another VM with Windows, and install Self hosted integration runtime there? That would be the best approach.

Comment: you should check that the Oracle database on the Linux Azure VM is listening on the specified port number

Answer (score 0):

> Connect ADF to Oracle DB hosted on Azure linux VM without SHIR

Due to the fact that the ADF Oracle connector uses SHIR to make a connection with oracle database on VM or on-premises, I don't believe it is feasible to connect to Oracle operating on a Linux virtual machine. As the only platform on which SHIR is presently available is Windows (see [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717) for system requirements).

As per prerequisites mentioned in [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites) :

> If your data store is located inside an on-premises network, an Azure virtual network, or Amazon Virtual Private Cloud, you need to configure a [self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to connect to it.